# navigate between features scenarios in cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, gherkin

I have two gherkin file the

1. first do the login with multiple user
2. and the second create multiple patient

here is my gherkin files:

```
  Scenario Outline: User Login
   Given user is on login page
    When user enters username and password from line <RowNumber> and clicks login
    Then check if login with data from line <RowNumber> was successful
    Examples:
      | RowNumber |
      | 0         |
      | 1         |
      | 2         |
```

- 

```
  Scenario Outline: Patient Creation
    Given   user is on the creation page of the application
    When user enters patient information from row <RowNumber>
    Then user checks that displayed errors are the same as row <RowNumber>
    Examples:
      | RowNumber |
      | 0         |
      | 1         |
      | 2         |
```

what I want is that when login with the first user I want to go to other scenario patine creation and create the 3 line and do the same with the 2 - 3 user

Comment: I would either leave the scenarios alone (they seem to be written fine to me) or combine the two scenarios into one scenario. Really they should be separate scenarios from a BDD perspective, but I've bent the rules from time to time and combined scenarios if the benefits outweigh the drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Test cases from scenarios should cover the appliaction and make it "safe". You can do the programing and just create sepparate method, or call the existing one that is transfered from gerkin into your step definitions.

Like inside of method "user enters username and password from line  and clicks login", you can call method from other step definition file like "user enters patient information from row " (not same text of method in step definition as in feature file).

But that should not be the case, remember you will count your scenarios for report, there is no magic trick you can do about it, can go with multiple assertions, but that is not recommended.

The real question is do you need that structure of scenarios and .feature files or you could write them in a better way. If can not, leave them as they are, you will not lose much on execution time.

Comment: My question was poorly asked and I believe that led to a misunderstanding for my objective. I posted a more detailed question with different examples of what I'm looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66705788/combining-multiple-external-datasets-with-cucumber-selenium-test-environments)